# Update SQL Service Pack Named Instance

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql

I have an existing SQL 2008 R2 on SP3.
Have another instance in use that is SQL 2008 R2 SP1

I need to update the named instance with sp1 to sp3 but i'm not getting any options.
It tells me my version is sp3 which for the named instance is not correct.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There are similar posts [like this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83643/sql-server-2008-r2-service-pack-3-wont-recognize-all-instances) on dba, which might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: When you run the installer, it should show all instances on the server that match the version, then show check boxes next to the ones that can be patched. DOUBLE CHECK the versions and editions and post both of them back here. SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion'), SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel'), SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the x64 or x86 version of the update, according to the installed instance. You can download both versions from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44271